# SPARK SQL: does groupBy after orderBy maintain that order?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have spark 2.3.0. In this example, does groupBy after orderBy maintain that order?

```
id date       name
1  2020-10-01 name1
1  2020-09-01 name2
1  2020-11-01 name3
```

This is the code:

```
df
  .orderBy(col("date"))
  .groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(
    first(col("name"))
  ).show()
```

The result i expect:

```
id name
1  name2
```

I read in old posts that the order is not maintained. But I did some tests and the sorting is maintained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not, there is *no guarantee*.

Shuffling and hashing due to groupBy means ordering is different than the preceding orderBy. It should be done after. That's the given from both old and new posts.